# Prawn - How can i allow unlimited height

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

On ruby when you create pdf using Prawn you can use:

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:page_size => [200, 900])
```

But I want to create a pdf with a fixed width (200) and unlimited maximum height with a minimum.

Something like this:

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:page_size => [200, {min: 400, max: :unlimited}])
```

The pdf in question is a ticket so I want to know if this is possible.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't make a PDF with unlimited height. What you want is probably set a dynamic height based on the content. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31856860/set-dynamically-height-for-entire-prawn-pdf-document

Comment: That could be useful too, thanks @nqngo. those questions are hard to find.